# Parcelable encountered IOException when providing custom listener through setArguments to Fragment

Tags: java, android, listener, notserializableexception

I have parent fragment that can open 3 different fragments, each of the 3 fragments can update same field in the parent fragment.
So i create super simple listener :

```
 public interface RatingUpdatedListener extends Serializable{
    //allow to set new rating from Gallery, Details, PersonalModel fragments into MyProfileFragment
    void onRatingUpdated(int rating);
}
```

When i load any child fragment i add via FragmentA.setArguments(bundle)

```
Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
        bundle.putSerializable(RATING_LISTENER, mRatingListener);
        fragment.setArguments(bundle);
```

and inside parent fragment i implemented this listener like this

```
private RatingUpdatedListener mRatingListener = new RatingUpdatedListener() {
        @Override
        public void onRatingUpdated(int rating) {

        }
    };
```

And then in child fragment i grab this listener:

```
mRatingUpdatedListener = (RatingUpdatedListener) getArguments().getSerializable(MyProfileFragment.RATING_LISTENER);
```

The problem when in one of the child fragments i opens CameraActivity or GalleryActivity using native android methods, i got :

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Parcelable encountered IOException writing serializable object
```

here are full Exception:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Parcelable encountered IOException writing serializable object (name = com.iseeya.iseeya.fragments.MyProfileFragment)
                                                                   at android.os.Parcel.writeSerializable(Parcel.java:1527)
                                                                   at android.os.Parcel.writeValue(Parcel.java:1475)
                                                                   at android.os.Parcel.writeArrayMapInternal(Parcel.java:724)
                                                                   at android.os.BaseBundle.writeToParcelInner(BaseBundle.java:1423)
                                                                   at android.os.Bundle.writeToParcel(Bundle.java:1157)
                                                                   at android.os.Parcel.writeBundle(Parcel.java:764)
                                                                   at android.support.v4.app.FragmentState.writeToParcel(Fragment.java:157)
                                                                   at android.os.Parcel.writeTypedArray(Parcel.java:1307)
                                                                   at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerState.writeToParcel(FragmentManager.java:617)
                                                                   at android.os.Parcel.writeParcelable(Parcel.java:1496)
                                                                   at android.os.Parcel.writeValue(Parcel.java:1402)
                                                                   at android.os.Parcel.writeArrayMapInternal(Parcel.java:724)
                                                                   at android.os.BaseBundle.writeToParcelInner(BaseBundle.java:1423)
                                                                   at android.os.Bundle.writeToParcel(Bundle.java:1157)
                                                                   at android.os.Parcel.writeBundle(Parcel.java:764)
                                                                   at android.app.ActivityManagerProxy.activityStopped(ActivityManagerNative.java:3683)
                                                                   at android.app.ActivityThread$StopInfo.run(ActivityThread.java:3830)
                                                                   at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:754)
                                                                   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
                                                                   at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:163)
                                                                   at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6276)
                                                                   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:898)
                                                                   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:788)
                                                                Caused by: java.io.NotSerializableException: android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatImageView
                                                                   at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject0(ObjectOutputStream.java:1224)
                                                                   at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.defaultWriteFields(ObjectOutputStream.java:1584)
                                                                   at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeSerialData(ObjectOutputStream.java:1549)
                                                                   at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeOrdinaryObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:1472)
                                                                   at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject0(ObjectOutputStream.java:1218)
                                                                   at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:346)
                                                                   at android.os.Parcel.writeSerializable(Parcel.java:1522)
                                                                   at android.os.Parcel.writeValue(Parcel.java:1475) 
                                                                   at android.os.Parcel.writeArrayMapInternal(Parcel.java:724) 
                                                                   at android.os.BaseBundle.writeToParcelInner(BaseBundle.java:1423) 
                                                                   at android.os.Bundle.writeToParcel(Bundle.java:1157) 
                                                                   at android.os.Parcel.writeBundle(Parcel.java:764) 
                                                                   at android.support.v4.app.FragmentState.writeToParcel(Fragment.java:157) 
                                                                   at android.os.Parcel.writeTypedArray(Parcel.java:1307) 
                                                                   at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerState.writeToParcel(FragmentManager.java:617) 
                                                                   at android.os.Parcel.writeParcelable(Parcel.java:1496) 
                                                                   at android.os.Parcel.writeValue(Parcel.java:1402) 
                                                                   at android.os.Parcel.writeArrayMapInternal(Parcel.java:724) 
                                                                   at android.os.BaseBundle.writeToParcelInner(BaseBundle.java:1423) 
                                                                   at android.os.Bundle.writeToParcel(Bundle.java:1157) 
                                                                   at android.os.Parcel.writeBundle(Parcel.java:764) 
                                                                   at android.app.ActivityManagerProxy.activityStopped(ActivityManagerNative.java:3683) 
                                                                   at android.app.ActivityThread$StopInfo.run(ActivityThread.java:3830) 
                                                                   at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:754) 
                                                                   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95) 
                                                                   at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:163) 
                                                                   at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6276) 
                                                                   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
                                                                   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:898) 
                                                                   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:788)
```

The question why doe's it fails on `NotSerializableException`if my listener doesn't have any objects?

Comment: Your OneThread Class also should implement Serializable. All the sub classes and inner sub classes must implements Serializable.

Comment: you mean the fragment? and why this happens only when i open camera or galley?

Comment: no, if model have inside another model and you want is Serializable then all inner model also should be Serializable.

Comment: But it is containing only one function that has int type argument